# Undefined property: Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::$name after image upload

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I am trying to get the exact uploaded image size by using getimagesize() php helper on Laravel 7. But i get an error

ErrorException: Undefined property: Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::$name on the line where the code is:

```
if($request->file('image') != null){
        $upload = $request->file('image');
        $sourceProperties = getimagesize($upload->name);
```

Please help understand the issues since it only occurs on the Debian server and not locally... It works fine on local

Comment: Try this `$request->file('image')->getSize();`

Comment: @sta This gives me a int  and not the image size information in an array such as:array:7 [
  0 => 474
  1 => 172
  2 => 2
  3 => "width="474" height="172""
  "bits" => 8
  "channels" => 3
  "mime" => "image/jpeg"
]; This way I can then get the width and height separately

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but after using the php helper getRealPath() as:

```
getimagesize($upload->getRealPath());
```

Works on the server but not locally.